# Proguard: can't find referenced method 'void addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable)' in library class java.lang.Throwable

Tags: java, android, proguard

When running ProGuard I get the following warning:

```
can't find referenced method 'void addSuppressed(java.lang.Throwable)' in library class java.lang.Throwable
```

Here is my proguard rule:

```
-injars build/libs/test-main-1.0.jar
-libraryjars /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Classes/classes.jar

-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-dontpreverify
-printusage
-dontnote

-keep public class com.foo.app.Main {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    static final % *;
    static final java.lang.String *;
}
```

Edit: I use proguard from the command line with the proguard.jar.

**How do I prevent this Warning? Isn't Throwable part of `classes.jar`?**

Comment: Android doesn't support that method; it was only added to normal Java in Java 7.  Approximately, this means that Android doesn't support try-with-resources, at least for many versions of Android.

Comment: I use proguard from the command line with the proguard.jar.

Comment: What should I do here to solve it?

Comment: you tagged this question with [android] -- are you actually trying to ProGuard this for Android?

Comment: you'll need to find where you're using try-with-resources in your application, and stop doing it.

Comment: You mean I cannot use java.lang.Throwable on Android?

Comment: No, I mean you can't use `java.lang.Throwable.addSuppressed` on Android, or any language constructs that use that method, like try-with-resources.  It's that specific method that is the issue, not the entire class.

Comment: This is strange because I do not use this method: addSuppressed

Comment: do you use try-with-resources anywhere?

Comment: I used this: ``try(DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())) {``   removing made it work.

Comment: yup, that's exactly what you should expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `addSuppressed` method, used in try with resources syntax, is not supported in Android.  Don't use that syntax and you'll be fine.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by changing my SDK version 18 to 19 in the file named `build.gradle`:

the old:

`compileSdkVersion 18`

now is:

`compileSdkVersion 19`